# CSS | Add right facing triangle on the end of a div

Tags: html, css

How can I add a right facing triangle to the end of a div? I want the content/size of the div to be the same, just with a right facing triangle on the right side of the div. Thanks.

Comment: `<div>content ►</div>` <- tada !

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your helpful reply, unfortunately it's not quite the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @adeneo Will this work in all browsers?

Comment: You're very welcome. Unfortunately, your question is lacking the quality we are looking for. I suggest you review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Paulie_D Where do you suggest I go to find help on this topic?

Comment: you can do it by creating a 0 width & 0 height element, with a thick border (without border-right), and set the color of border-top and border-bottom to transparent.

Comment: @JDoe - yes, that will work in all browsers, it's just a triangle character

Comment: @AllenWong Will this work with content in the div? Or will I have to position these triangles at the end of each div?

Comment: this will work with both div and ::after/::before. Of course, you have to position them outside the box.

Answer (score 4):

For right arrow in the middle of the content box

```css
.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #88b7d5;
  border: 2px solid #c2e1f5;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
}
.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-left-color: #88b7d5;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
  border-left-color: #c2e1f5;
  border-width: 13px;
  margin-top: -13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```